# Getting the HtmlEditor control to work on a SharePoint 2007 Application Page

Tags: 2007, application-pages, publishing, html-editor

I need to use the HtmlEditor control within an application page in SharePoint 2007 but I'm unable to get it to work. Do you have any ideas what I need to do? Using the following aspx code the editor appears on the page but I get JavaScript errors when I try to use it.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/application.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ID="Main" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderMain" >
    Publishing:HtmlEditor <Publishing:HtmlEditor runat="server"  />
</asp:Content>
```

To use this code place it in an aspx file within the layouts directory and browse from a SharePoint site (e.g. /_layouts/testpage.aspx). You will also need to have MOSS installed as this is a control from the Publishing namespace.

Hope you can help. Thanks.

James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working. It turns out I need to manually add a reference to another JavaScript file, as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/form.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think HTML editor is not intended to use that way.Is it possible to use Content Editor Web Part instead?

Comment: I want the users to be able to insert images and links (as well as text) from SharePoint content so the asset selectors are very useful. I've actually got it working and will add an answer shortly.